# Drupal CDN module & Fileconveyor daemon to use with Amazon S3 server for content delivery

Tags: drupal, module, amazon-s3, integration, cdn

I am using the Drupal's CDN module & Python's fileconveyor daemon to synchronize the website media files to Amazon S3 server. 
Does anyone know any drawback/disadvanctage by use of these modules.

Is there any alternative module available in Drupal to use with Amazon S3 & Amazon CDN in a website?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No drawbacks, just make sure you're using nagios to monitor file conveyor's daemon. It can sometimes die. Also just a little tip... if you're using [file conveyor](https://github.com/wimleers/fileconveyor), make sure you've got the [transliteration module](http://drupal.org/project/transliteration) installed. Python tends to not like non-utf8 characters in file names.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. File conveyor uses sqlite to maintain the state of files to be synced. Don't you think it is a scalability bottleneck. We are deploying a site that is media intensive & we expect the traffic to grow as exponentially.

Comment: I think the benefits out weigh the risks. We had been using rsync and cron but our file system got too big to run rsync every 5 minutes over 100GB. That's why File Conveyor responding to inotify is nice. On the other hand if you can directly put some media assets into S3 without the upstream sync that's even better. Could look into http://drupal.org/project/media_amazon if you're using D7.

Comment: Can you provide me some tips on how can I monitor the file conveyor's daemon using nagios. That will be helpful to me. Thanks.

Comment: Look forward for your comments on monitoring file conveyor via nagios. In addition, can you recommend any other tool for monitoring conveyor?

Comment: Just in general, we created an init.d script that nohups python arbitrator.py. Then we keep an eye on daemon.log to see if the file size is changing. We're looking for a delta because the log rotates every 5.1MB. Also our solution might not be the best because we're constantly syncing files upstream. There isn't a pause while waiting for inotify to kick off a sync task.